# If I get my Private Pilots License before college, how far will that set me ahead, if at all?

Tags: ppl

So I am looking into getting my PPL and I was wondering if there was any benefit when it comes to college. I am wanting to go to Purdue, preferably, and major in Professional Flight. If I went ahead in getting my PPL now would that get me ahead in college? If it doesn't I don't think it would be worth spending all that money.

Answer (score 3):

Well, since you want to go to Purdue specifically, a good place to start would be the [Purdue Professional Flight website](https://polytechnic.purdue.edu/degrees/professional-flight/faq#Students).  I found this there:

> FAQ: Students Coming to School with a Private Pilot’s Certificate. Is there an advantage?

> Depending on each individual situation, a student coming in with their Private Pilot’s Certificate can be either an advantage or disadvantage. The only real difference is cost. Sometimes it is more cost efficient for a student to get their certificate from Purdue or an outside flight school. It is ultimately up to the student.

Comment: Well that's one of the most non-answer answers I've seen! Good find.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: Though the problem's not with the answer, but with real life.  If your family owns a plane, it's probably a lot cheaper to get your PPL in it, than if you have to rent one from an FBO.